# Dataframe or index make symetrical based on the upper triangle

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to make the data frame df symmetrical based on the upper numbers.
As can be seen in the example in the picture.
[Example]

[image: 1]

Any ideas how could this be done most efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
import numpy as np

arr = df.to_numpy()
out = pd.DataFrame(np.triu(arr, 0) + np.triu(arr, 1).T)
```